# A specific exe file can not be called programmatically

Tags: c#, c, vb.net, windows-8.1

Windows 8.1 comes with a feature called "SlideToShutdown". I am trying to call that executable file programmatically. I tried `Process.Start();` in C#, `Shell()` in VB and `(void)system();` in C. 

It says error as `'C:\Windows\System32\SlideToShutdown.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. 
But in command prompt when I execute `start C:\windows\system32\slidetoshutdown.exe` it works perfectly.

[image]

This is my C program (named a.c) to call it

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    (void)system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\SlideToShutDown.exe");
    return(0);
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: what's with the tags? this looks like C.

Comment: @dandan78 OP tried C#, VB.NET and C. He likely wants a solution in any of these languages.

Comment: @st you are correct, my mistake.

Comment: Is the issue specific to `SlideToShutdown.exe`? What happens when you try to launch Notepad? Your code works on my Win7 system (when launching Notepad).

Comment: @Stijn, launching notepad, mspaint are working perfactly. But only that specific exe file not working. PLEASE READ THE TITLE CAREFULLY "A specific exe file can not be called programatically"

Comment: Relax, no need to yell.

Comment: Can someone on Win8.1 confirm this? It's so weird. Also, maybe you could try looking into it with a PE editor to see if this is a valid executable file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using the 64-bit version of Windows.  Your program is however a 32-bit process.  It is subjected to [*file system redirection*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it will actually look in the c:\windows\syswow64 directory for the program.  The home directory for 32-bit executables.  Where it doesn't exist.

The workaround is to use `c:\windows\sysnative\slidetoshutdown.exe`.  The "sysnative" part of the directory name will be mapped to system32 for a 32-bit process.  You should technically also lookup the home directory, it isn't necessarily c:\windows.  GetWindowsDirectory() function.

If you do this in a managed project then simply change the Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target setting.  Favor AnyCPU, turn off the "Prefer 32-bit" option for VS2012 and up.  Which will make your program run as a 64-bit process and thus won't get redirected.  Now simply Process.Start("slidetoshutdown.exe") will work.  Creating a 64-bit C program isn't hard either, just change the target platform to x64.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already tried this, anyway I suggest:

```
system("start C:\\windows\\system32\\slidetoshutdown.exe");
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("start","C:\\windows\\system32\\slidetoshutdown.exe")
```

Comment: This looks so ugly :D